# Set a cell equal to another cell with a hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I set one cell's value equal to another cell? Ensuring hyperlinks, formatting, equations, etc. all transfer accordingly.

I know I can type "=" into cell A then click on cell B, but if cell B contains an external hyperlink or formatting then it doesn't transfer to cell A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References to other cells will never transport format or hyperlinks, only the cell's underlying value. In some cases, like dates, Excel will recognize the format of the source cell and adapt that format to the target cell, too, but that only applies to the date display, not formatting like font or color.

If you know that a cell contains a hyperlink, then you can use the Hyperlink() function and refer to that cell.

```
=HYPERLINK(A1,A1)
```

That function will always return a hyperlink, regardless of the actual contents of the referred cell, so you need to make sure it is only used with real hyperlinks.

Comment: +1 Thank you! That solved the hyperlink problem, and that's what seemed to be the case with formatting. Using the function you suggested worked very well with dragging this down & right: `=HYPERLINK('WKSHTA'!A5,'WKSHTA'!A5)` (which also works well with $ around the cell values)